# Looping fluid sim for boot animation?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I am making a fluid simulation for a boot animation. In the animation, a cup fills up with water and overflows. I want to have seamless loop of water overflowing out of the cup. Anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps fluid sim is to random and would be difficult to match ends up, I would suggest hacking with particles and metaballs or remeshing particles with the cubesurfer addon http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?352233-BETA-CubeSurfer-addon-(mesher